# Nested Ng-repeat with ng-if passing proper $index

Tags: angularjs

I have a nested `ng-repeat` with `ng-if`, inside each `ng-if` I have a check-box which is containing a `ng-click` function. I want to pass the nested `ng-repeat`'s `$index` value through the function.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="student" ng-repeat="student in studentDetails.childNumber track by $index" ng-init=" studentnumber = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="grmnt in student.garmentNumber track by $index" ng-init="grmntidex = $index" ng-if="grmnt.gurmentType === 'shirt'">
    <div ng-click="garmentOpen = !garmentOpen;" class="z-depth-1 garmentelement">Garment</div>
    <div class="garmentHeader" ng-if="garmentOpen">
      <div class="garmentBody">
        <div class="row">
          <p class="col s6 center-align">
            <input type="checkbox" id="BrandMeasurement" ng-click="msrmntSelector(grmnt)" />
            <label for="BrandMeasurement">Brand Measurement</label>
          </p>
          <p class="col s4 center-align">
            <input type="checkbox" id="BodyMeasurement" ng-click="msrmntSelector(grmnt)" />
            <label for="BodyMeasurement">Body Measurement</label>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is when I am selecting the last `grmnt` element it's passing proper garment with `id` but after selecting the first element its not passing 2nd or 3rd or 4th any of the garment. In every case it's passing only the first element.

Can any one please tell me where I'm making any mistake (if any)??

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ng-if` on the `ng-repeat` just use a filter in the `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="grmnt in student.garmentNumber | filter:{gurmentType: 'shirt'} track by $index" ng-init="grmntidex = $index">
```

Edit: I think maybe the problem is in your labels. The label's `for` attribute needs to uniquely match the input's `id` attribute. Each row needs its own `id`/`for` pair. Use `$index` to do this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="BrandMeasurement{{$index}}" ng-click="msrmntSelector(grmnt)" />
<label for="BrandMeasurement{{$index}}">Brand Measurement</label>
```

Comment: but with out ng-if i'm also having the same problem

Comment: I think I might know why, but first why do you have two identical checkboxes?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: actualy i have two select box based on check box answer that will updated.

Comment: Yes it works Thank You So much. but what i know that scope is not related with id/for. then why this two things make problem with ng-click function?? can you please explain it??

Comment: It isn't AngularJS or JavaScript at all. The `id`/`for` relationship is a pure HTML requirement. The label has to know what unique form element it is associated with. If multiple inputs have that ID then the browser can send events to the wrong one.